# Map function not return item in render reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here is code, why my map function not return item in div.
I have use array of object in state function.
Here is my simple code.
I have XML data in **componentwiillrecieveprops**. is there any issue by **componentwillmount**. I do not understand why map function in map my array of state.

```js
import React from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
var self;

export default class NewAuthoring extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        self = this;
        this.state = {
            sampleState : "OriginalState",
            task : [
                {event:"First data",eventpara:"First Data"},
                {event:"Second data",eventpara:"Second Data"},
                {event:"Third data",eventpara:"Third Data"}
            ]
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log(nextProps.xml)
        if(this.props != nextProps) {
            //Do Something when any props recieve
            this.setState({sampleState:nextProps.xml});
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        //Do something before component renders
        let xml ="<div type=”timeline/slideshow”><section><header></header><article></article></section><section><header></header><article></article></section><section><header></header><article></article></section><section><header></header><article></article></section></div>";
        self.props.getChildXml(xml);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        //Do Something when component is mounted

    }

    handleChange(e) {
        //getChildXml function will update the xml with the given 
        //parameter and will also change the xml dialog value
        let xml ="<div type=”timeline/slideshow”><section><header></header><article></article></section><section><header></header><article></article></section><section><header></header><article></article></section><section><header></header><article></article></section></div>";
        self.props.getChildXml(xml);
    }

    render() {
        const myStyle = {
            mainBlock:{
                fontWeight:"bold",
                margin:"2px"
            }
        }
        const div_style = {
            border:'1px solid black',
            margin:10
        }
        {
            this.state.task.map((item,contentIndex) => {
                return (<div>
                    hello
                    {item.event}
                    {item.eventpara} 
                </div>)
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not returning element from `map` callback. Also i see that `tasks` is an array of object, and you are directly rendering object by writting `{item}`. You need to return the element and should avoid rendering object directly like this

```
           {
                this.state.task.map((item,contentIndex) => {
                    return (<div>
                        hello
                        {item.event}
                        {item.eventpara} 
                    </div>)
                })
            }
```

Alternatively you can also avoid use of `{}` brackets to return the element without writting `return` keyword.

```
{
   this.state.task.map((item,contentIndex) => (
     <div>
        hello
        {item.event}
        {item.eventpara} 
     </div>
   ))
}
```

UPDATE: You need to return something from render function

```
render() {
        const myStyle = {
            mainBlock:{
                fontWeight:"bold",
                margin:"2px"
            }
        }
        const div_style = {
            border:'1px solid black',
            margin:10
        }

        return (
          <div>
          {
            this.state.task.map((item,contentIndex) => {
                return (<div>
                    hello
                    {item.event}
                    {item.eventpara} 
                </div>)
            })
          }
          </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: NewAuthoring.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object. >>>>>>> I am getting this error in console

Comment: You must return something from `render` function. Make sure you are returning some element from render function.

Comment: so i return the hello inside the map function... or what should i do please help if it work then i start my project

Comment: Also, the return elements should be a single element. Not an array of element. If possible, update the question with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the map pattern is very common in React you could also do something like this:

**1: Create a Map/Iterator component**

```
const Iterator = (props) => {
  //you could validate proptypes also...
  if(!props.array.length) return null
  return props.array.map(element => props.component(element))

}
```

**2.return it passing the component as props:**

```
 render() {
        const myStyle = {
            mainBlock:{
                fontWeight:"bold",
                margin:"2px"
            }
        }
        const div_style = {
            border:'1px solid black',
            margin:10
        }
        return <Iterator
                   array={this.state.task}
                   component={ 
                   item=>(<div key={item.event}>hello{item.event} 
                   {item.eventpara} } </div>                           
                />              
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're returning nothing in `render()`. Use it as follows:

```
render(){
    return(
        {this.state.task.map((item,contentIndex) => {
                return <SomeElement />;
         }
    );
}
```