# React content rendering based on map output not working

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I have a component which is going to rely on the results of an array.map to determine it's output. In this case the array contains an element called "name", and one of the names is 'Welcome.' What needs to happen is the component spits out a particular div for the 'Welcome' instance and different content (an Accordion component) for every other instance. I've used a ternary operator in the render which I'm then calling in the return, but it's outputting the same text for every instance of the component (the text specified for only the 'Welcome' instance.) I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
export default class Back extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props)
}

render() {

 const CheckDomains = this.props.totaldomains.map((domain, index) => {    
    <div>
    {
      domain.name === 'Welcome' ?
        <div>This is welcome text.</div>
      :
        <div>This is accordion text.</div>
    }
    </div>
   )
 });


 return(
      <div className='back'>
        {CheckDomains}
      </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map function not return item in render reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063814/map-function-not-return-item-in-render-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something in your map callback function.

Like so:

```
const CheckDomains = this.props.totaldomains.map((domain, index) => {    
  return  (
      <div>
          {
            domain.name === 'Welcome' ?
              <div>This is welcome text.</div>
            :
              <div>This is accordion text.</div>
          }
        </div>
    )
});
```

Comment: That solution is putting outputting both divs on top of each other on every instance of the component.

Comment: Can I see the JSON of your `this.props.totaldomains`?

Comment: @CHays412 I have tried to replicate it in this sandbox env and it is working - https://codesandbox.io/s/z3jp1lxv9p

Comment: awesome I will check this out! Thank you so much.